# Multiple FullCalendars on one page

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using the `FullCalendar.js` plugin to create a page with multiple calendars on it. As in the [external-events](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.0/demos/external-dragging.html) sample I am able to drag external events onto every of the calendars. Only after changing the view (with prev,next) method in one of the calendars, I cannot drag events onto the other calendars anymore. The day cells do not get highlighted when I drag an external event over them and drop doesn't work either.

Note that dragging already created events within every calendar on its own still works fine. But drag/drop of external events only works for the calendar where I changed/prev/next the date.

Note that I do not want to drag events between the various calendars!

I tried a short snippet of javascript to change dates of calendars synchronously by triggering the `'prev', 'next'` methods of the remaining calendars. In that case drag/drop only works for the last calendar where the date being changed.

It is a strange behaviour. Does FullCalendar use some global settings etc. which might influence other calendar instances on one page? I debugged the method invoked by 'prev', 'next' etc. but the do not seem to change anything globally.

I create the calendars in seperate `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FullCalendar registers eventhandlers for 'mousedown' and 'dragstart' on the html document to make external dropping of events possible. These handler functions are bound to specific context using $.proxy() first and then added/removed to the document with jQuery functions .on() and .off(). The jQuery Doc states on the usage of .off() with .proxy():

> Handlers proxied by jQuery.proxy() or a similar mechanism will all
>   have the same unique id (the proxy function), so passing proxied
>   handlers to .off may remove more handlers than intended. In those
>   situations it is better to attach and remove event handlers using
>   namespaces.

Navigating through a FullCalendar unsing prev, next buttons etc. invokes a redraw of the current View (Monthview etc.), which involves destroying the current view and detaching document event handlers:

```
// taken from FullCalendar.js 2.1.1
destroy: function() {
    this.unselect();
    this.trigger('viewDestroy', this, this, this.el);
    this.destroyEvents();
    this.el.empty(); // removes inner contents but leaves the element intact

    $(document)
        .off('mousedown', this.documentMousedownProxy)
        .off('dragstart', this.documentDragStartProxy);    // all handlers removed here
},
```

As $.proxy() has given same identifier for event handlers of seperate FullCalendar instances, this call detaches handlers for all instances.

A quick solution is to use namespaces for events. I generate a unique event namespace inside the view class in FullCalendar and atach/detach the respective events using that namespace:

```
View.prototype = {

    // ...

    // declare namespace 
    documentEventNamespace: null,

    init: function() {

        // ...

        // define namespace, simply with random number
        this.documentEventNamespace = "fcDocumentEvents" + parseInt(Math.random() * 1000);
    },

    render: function() {

        // ...

        // use namespace for events
        $(document)
            .on('mousedown.' + this.documentEventNamespace, this.documentMousedownProxy)
            .on('dragstart.' + this.documentEventNamespace, this.documentDragStartProxy); // jqui drag
    },


    // Clears all view rendering, event elements, and unregisters handlers
    destroy: function() {

        // use namespace for events
        $(document)
            .off('mousedown.' + this.documentEventNamespace, this.documentMousedownProxy)
            .off('dragstart.' + this.documentEventNamespace, this.documentDragStartProxy);
    },

    // ...
}
```

This is a hack that works, but I would prefer a solution without touching FullCalendar.js code. Maybe someone else has a hint on that, or FullCalendar will use event namespace in a future update.